# EOB says $4k total charges, $4k ineligible charges, PR $0, still got bill from the provider for $1431

Tags: united-states, health-insurance, medical-bill

The EOB for the service (epidural) says that:

- charge: $4000
- allowed charge: $0
- ineligible: $4000
- patient responsibility: $0
- ineligibility code: 1 - The Provider is not eligible to receive reimbursement for these services, per provider contract.

In a year and a half we received a bill from the provider for $1431 for the same date of service. I have no idea where this magic number $1431 is coming from.

I tried to call the provider, they said to call the insurance. Trying to reach the insurance now, but...

Is this correct that we are not supposed to pay and the provider should figure it out with the insurance why insurance does not reimburse the provider? Does patient responsibility $0 mean that there is nothing we should pay or do?

UPD: the provider is in-network, we checked that before and I can still confirm it on the insurance website it shows as in-network

Comment: is the provider in-network?

Comment: Thanks for asking, yes, it is in-network, I can find that provider on the insurance website. It was labor, there were many different charges. All went through as expected according to EOB, except this one for this particular provider.

Comment: I don't think anyone can answer this question. American healthcare is a bottomless pit of despair that works in mysterious ways. If I were to guess I'd say that this bill is a result of the provider trying to bully you into giving them some money since they couldn't get it from the insurance. Depending on your stamina and ability to deal with the American medical bureaucracy you may or may not be able to successfully push back.

Comment: Laws vary by state, in my state what you describe would not be allowed. Your insurer should be able to help clear things up.

Comment: I'm in WA, just in case...

Comment: WA  Balance Billing Protection Act is relevant then, but insurer still best resource initially.

Comment: That is great to know, thanks!